# Does exception handling rollback actions done before the exception occurred?

Tags: java, exception

Imagine I have a method like this

```
void myMethod(MyThing t) throws MyException {
   t.foo = "bar";
   if (t.condition()) { 
      throw new MyException();
   }
}
```

If the exception is triggered, does the value of t.foo revert to whatever it was previously? Or does it keep the "bar" value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The value of the foo property on your MyThing object will not revert on any Exception.

In your example, there is no `try` block, but if there were one, you could perform your own type of rollback of the value in a corresponding `catch` block.

```
try {
    t.foo = "bar";
    doSomethingRiskyWhichMightThrowMyException();
} catch(MyException e) {
    t.foo = "rolledbackvalue";
}
```

Comment: Thought so. Damn! It would have been so convenient. 

(I was thinking of using Exceptions to trap a "fail" condition in a recursive tree searching / transforming algorithm which is difficult to unwind manually.)

Comment: @insterstar If you use a stack (call-stack, or explicit) and *immutable types* then there often little need to "unwind manually".

Comment: @pst good point. Unfortunately, I have a whole hierarchy of moving things who's positions I'm updating. I didn't start by writing them as immutable objects ... hmmm ...

Comment: @interstar - another common approach is to do all of your checking before start updating state that would need to be rolled back.

Answer (score 4):

`Throwing / catching` exceptions *does not* automatically imply any rollback operation.

If a variable `foo` was changed before the exception was thrown the value will remain changed afterwards as well.

Answer (score 3):

The value will not change to its previous value. In fact that is what you are to do in the catch block. If an exception of that type occurs, you can reinitialize the value in the catch block. Try catch blocks just enable you to perform operations so that you don't fall into a trap forever. What should be done, whether to rollback or not in the event of such an exception is totally the programmer's decision.

Answer (score 2):

Any code follows the sequential pattern. i.e. First statement First and so on(unless you have some loops to repeat statements or goto statements to skip or repeat blocks).
In your example, after it throws the exception, the control of execution will go to Java's Exception Handler(since you have not written any Exception handling code via try-catch blocks) and finally end abruptly. So it will not in any case "retrace" it's path and go back to restoring the t.foo value. It remains the "bar" string only.Hope it helps.